# JSON to CSV conversion using Java

Tags: java, json

Is there any way to convert multiple JSON files into one CSV-file ?

My JSON file is like this:

```
{
  "Title" : {
      "name" : "ABC",
      "id" : "1",
      "job": "Teacher"    
      },
      "Circle":{
                "area":"2R"
        },
        "Triangle":{
                "length":"45"
        }
}
```

If you will see, this JSON has 3 roots and different elements under each root.
How to convert this JSON to CSV so that it can be opened in excel and can be viewed as follows:

```
Title
Name  ABC
id    1
job   Teacher
Circle
area  2r
Triangle
length  45
```

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: I suggest you to use a [`JSON parser`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Comment: I can't think of a use-case for this. You'd lose the structure of your data. You won't be able to re-create the JSON from the CSV.

Comment: This is going to be quite silly I just can't help myself. Have you thought about `jsonString.replaceAll("[\\\"\\{\\}\\:\\,]"," ");` because that produces something very  similar to your CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would say that you should first parse you JSON with something like [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), and then you can write down a CSV file by using their [extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv). That's an option.

Other way might be to use an external tool to do the conversion, such as [json2csv](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a library [json2flat](https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat). It converted your json

```
{
  "Title" : {
      "name" : "ABC",
      "id" : "1",
      "job": "Teacher"    
      },
      "Circle":{
                "area":"2R"
        },
        "Triangle":{
                "length":"45"
        }
}
```

to the following

```
/Title/name,/Title/id,/Title/job,/Circle/area,/Triangle/length
"ABC","1","Teacher","2R","45"
```

Hope it helps. After all it depends upon users how they want to interpret it.